# Nested JSON - Retrieve a paramater using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

Trying to retrieve parameters such as **description**, or **bannerUrl**, but to no avail. Any suggestions? Nothing seems to output...

How can get get those values?

I have tried the below, but no luck:

```
import games from "../JSON/US.en.json";
```

```
{games.map((value,key)=>
                       <div>{value.description}</div>
        )}
```

```
[
{
    "70010000000025": {
        "**bannerUrl**": "xxxx",
        "category": [
            "Adventure",
            "Action",
            "RPG",
            "Other"
        ],
        "**description**": "xxxx",
        "developer": null,
        "frontBoxArt": null,
        "iconUrl": "https://img-eshop.cdn.nintendo.net/i/d3c210e61e8487200fc4c344987243a60257838187a69a6a81c42d7447d5d192.jpg",
        "id": "01007EF00011E000",
    }
]
```

As per the description above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `json` data is not formatted properly in your `..en.json` file. First you need to format that. Then you transform the JSON data from an object with keys as properties into an array of objects.

```js
// en.json file content
{
  "70010000000025": {
    ...
  }
}

// App.jsx
const data = [games];

const gamesArray = Object.entries(data[0]).map(([key, value]) => ({
  key,
  ...value
}));

{gamesArray.map((game, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <div>Description: {game.description}</div>
          <div>Banner URL: {game.bannerUrl}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-ishizaka-nmx3f9?file=/src/App.js)***

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{value["**bannerUrl**"]}
```

Also notice that your data is nested inside another object **70010000000025**:

```json
    "70010000000025":
        "**bannerUrl**": "xxxx",
        "category": [
            "Adventure",
            "Action",
            "RPG",
            "Other"
        ],
        "**description**": "xxxx",
        "developer": null,
        "frontBoxArt": null,
        "iconUrl": "https://img-eshop.cdn.nintendo.net/i/d3c210e61e8487200fc4c344987243a60257838187a69a6a81c42d7447d5d192.jpg",
        "id": "01007EF00011E000",
    }
```